# Collections.sort(emptyList()): cannot infer type-variable

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8

What the?  This compile error occurs with `javac` (1.8.0_121) but builds and runs fine in Eclipse (4.6.2).

An extremely minimalized code follows:

```
import java.util.Collections;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collections.sort(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

(I'm not concerned about semantics.  The original code isn't `Collections.sort()` but something with similar signature.)

For this, `javac` prints:

```
error: no suitable method found for sort(List<Object>)
                Collections.sort(Collections.emptyList());
                           ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: Object
        upper bound(s): Comparable<? super Object>,Object)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
1 error
```

Is there something I can do to `javac` to make this compile?  Should I just consider this a limitation in Java 8 and code a workaround?

Changing to `Collections.<Comparable<Object>>sort(Collections.emptyList());` makes it compile.

Comment: Looks like this [bug in Java 8 that will be fixed come Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033718).

Comment: Nope. According to the JBT link the bug you are referring to has been resolved in Java 8 a long time ago (8u20/8u25).

Comment: Oic, you mean the **Backports** section... Different bug then, but which...

Comment: Doesn't compile with Java 9 ea b159 either (with the same error messsage).

Comment: @Stefan Zobel: there is no reason to infer `List<Object>` here. And `javac` has no problems inferring, e.g. `List<String>` or `List<Comparable<Foo>>`. It only fails at `<T extends Comparable<T>> List<T>`…

Comment: @Holger Ah, I see now what you mean. I tried with `List<Comparable<Foo>>` and indeed it works. So, the mere fact that sort() has this more restrictive signature should drive the inference towards assuming that this is also the return type of emptyList(), right?

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question but still doesn't have an accepted answer.

Assuming that the objects are comparable, such as String class, I would simply change this as follows:

```
Collections.sort(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

or break this into two steps:

```
List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
Collections.sort(s);
```

As updated in the original question, the following also works, if you don't want to make any change to `Collections.emptyList()`:

```
Collections.<Comparable<Object>>sort(Collections.emptyList());
```